# F# - CSV to two keys dictionary

Tags: csv, f#

I have localization CSV file with following structure

```
Key, Language1, Language2, Language3
some key, translation1, translation2, translation3
```

I'd like to write function that return multidimensional array from what I can easy get translation. E.g.

`translations["some key"]["Language1"]` returns me "translation1"

I wrote only loading of file

```
open GleedsSnags.Localization
open FSharp.Data

type Loc = CsvProvider<"Localization.csv">
let locData = Loc.Load("Localization.csv")
```

but I don't know what data structure is best for this issue and how to construct result in F# in most elegant way. Then I'd like to read this structure in C#.

Any idea?

Comment: Its somewhat unclear how your indexes relate to each other.  Could you elaborate on that point a bit?

Comment: You can get a map out of a csvprovider like this: `let myMap = Loc.Rows |> Seq.map (fun r -> r.Key, r) |> Map.ofSeq
// accessing translations:
let trans1 = myMap.["some key"].Language1
let trans2 = myMap.["some key"].Language2
` but the type of each row is generated by the type provider. If you want a more robust solution in terms of interoperability with other libraries you can write a loop that will copy the data into a `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>`. This can be done by a simple for loop.

Comment: @mydogisbox they are not related. Simply one key has multiple translations.

Comment: @jpe thank you a lot. it is really hard to understand your solution from inline code, but i will try

Comment: Oh, I was reading that totally wrong.  @jpe has a good solution

Comment: In this case I think you'd be better off not using the `CsvProvider`, since you actually want to treat the columns homogenously rather than as strongly typed entities.

Answer (score 4):

Using type providers you can achieve the following easily:

```
open FSharp.Data

type Loc = CsvProvider<"Localization.csv">

let myMap = Loc.Rows |> Seq.map (fun r -> r.Key, r) |> Map.ofSeq

// accessing translations:
let trans1 = myMap.["some key"].Language1
let trans2 = myMap.["some key"].Language2
```

Here the type of each row in the map is generated by the type provider and it may cause trouble when passing the result around between different libraries.

On the other hand, there is also another tool for dealing with CSV files in the FSharp.Data module, namely `CsvFile`:

```
open FSharp.Data

let csv = CsvFile.Load("Localization.csv")
// To use the dynamic operator '?'
open FSharp.Data.CsvExtensions
// For Dictionary
open System.Collections.Generic

let myMap2 = csv.Rows |> Seq.map (fun r -> r?Key, r) |> Map.ofSeq 
let dict  = Dictionary(myMap2)
```

Now you have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string,CsvRow>` that can be accessed as follows:

```
dict.["some key"].["Language1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z(v=vs.110).aspx

If you need to do it this way, you have your files and may possibly do something like:

```
let translation key language = 
 let d = 
  locData
  |> Seq.filter(fun x -> x.Key = key)
  |> Seq.exactlyone
 d.[language]
```

To speed stuff up, use some Map or something:

```
let mapLocData = 
 locData 
 |> Seq.groupBy (fun x -> x.Key)
 |> Map.ofSeq

let translation key language = 
  mapLocData.[key].[language]
```

...ish...

code not at all tested, and only written here etc.

Comment: This does not quite work. `mapLocData is of type Map<string, seq<CsvProvider<...>.Row>>` and you cannot access the language like you suggest.

Comment: I knew the "solution"/code as is, would not work. Regard it as some pseudocode, and trim it to work. The general idea is there. @jpe was less lazy than me and bothered to write it all out ;-)